# Transform dates from table into columns in MS Access query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table like below:

| type_id | date | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 2021-06-23 | 123 |
| 20 | 2021-06-23 | 217 |
| 35 | 2021-06-23 | 121 |
| 35 | 2021-06-24 | 128 |
| 20 | 2021-06-24 | 55 |
| 35 | 2021-06-25 | 77 |
| 20 | 2021-06-26 | 72 |
| 20 | 2021-06-26 | 71 |

and want to create **a query** only where type_id=20 likie this:

| 2021-06-23 | 2021-06-24 | 2021-06-25 | 2021-06-25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 55 |  | 72 |
| 217 |  |  | 71 |

- is it possible to do this with sql without vba?
- if vba needed do I need to create a extra table and every time add/delete a new columns ?

Thnak You for any idea

Comment: I think you might be looking into something similar to this here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks, I thought I searched all helpful topics but didn't reach this ...

Comment: Keep in mind there is is a limit of 255 columns. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: June 7 - unfortunately no, it didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  But this is a pain in MS Access because you need a sequential value.  You can calculate one:

```
select max(iif(date = "2021-06-23", order, null)) as val_2021_06_23,
       max(iif(date = "2021-06-24", order, null)) as val_2021_06_24,
       max(iif(date = "2021-06-25", order, null)) as val_2021_06_25,
       max(iif(date = "2021-06-26", order, null)) as val_2021_06_26       
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t as t2
              where t2.type_id = t.type_id and t2.date = t.date and t2.order <= t.order
             ) as seqnum
      from t
      where type_id = 20
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You, it works !
(only one change in the code needed "2021-06-23" ----> #2021-06-23#

In the meantime I found a other solution but this need add a new field into the table. The field is a numeric field which contain sequence numer for each day from 1 to n. In my project it's even helpful because in this case I can control order by in columns

here is the code. maybe helpful for someone in future

```
TRANSFORM
First ([tabela1].[order])
SELECT  [tabela1].[sequence]
FROM  [tabela1]
WHERE [tabela1].[type_id] = 20
GROUP BY [tabela1].[sequence]
PIVOT  [tabela1].[date]
```